# unable to parse soap response using Azure API Management liquid template

Tags: azure-api-management, liquid-template

I want to change the output format of the soap response, before passing it onto the client. I am using the soap pass-through as specified in the documentation https://azure.microsoft.com/en-ca/blog/soap-pass-through/

Soap service used in this example is hosted at
https://fazioapisoap.azurewebsites.net/FazioService.svc?singleWsdl

I am unable to extract the soap response in the liquid template. Soap response does get generated, however, there is no data.

[image]

Is there anything wrong with this code?

```
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
            <value>text/xml</value>
        </set-header>
        <set-body template="liquid">
            <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
                <soapenv:Header />
                <soapenv:Body>
                    <tem:GetOpenOrders>
                        <!--Optional:-->
                        <tem:cust>{{body.Envelope.Body.GetOpenOrders.cust}}</tem:cust>
                    </tem:GetOpenOrders>
                </soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>
        </set-body>
        <base />
    </inbound>
    <backend>
        <base />
    </backend>
    <outbound>
        <set-body template="liquid">
            <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                <s:Body>
                    <GetOpenOrdersResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
                        <GetOpenOrdersResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/FazioAPISoap" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">                        
  {% for summary in body.Envelope.Body.GetOpenOrdersResponse.GetOpenOrdersResult.OrderSummary -%}
    <a:OrderSummary><a:order_id>{{summary.order_id}}</a:order_id></a:OrderSummary>
  {% endfor -%}
     </GetOpenOrdersResult>
                    </GetOpenOrdersResponse>
                </s:Body>
            </s:Envelope>
        </set-body>
        <set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
            <value>text/xml</value>
        </set-header>
        <base />
    </outbound>
    <on-error>
        <base />
    </on-error>
</policies>
```

Comment: is it because of namespace prefix before each element, I cannot access this value? `<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http:..">
   <s:Body>
      <GetOpenOrdersResponse xmlns="http:.">
         <GetOpenOrdersResult xmlns:a="http://.." 
            <a:OrderSummary>
               <a:order_header_data>
                  <a:Bar>false</a:Bar>
                  <a:Foo>Things</a:Foo>
               </a:order_header_data>
               <a:order_id>10001</a:order_id>
            </a:OrderSummary>         
         </GetOpenOrdersResult>
      </GetOpenOrdersResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>`

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to prefix the namespaces. This requests is valid

```
<set-body template="liquid">
    <Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <Body>
            <GetOpenOrdersResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
                <GetOpenOrdersResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/FazioAPISoap" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">                        
  {% for summary in body.Envelope.Body.GetOpenOrdersResponse.GetOpenOrdersResult.OrderSummary -%}
                    <OrderSummary>
                        <order_id>
                            {{summary.order_id}}
                        </order_id>
                    </OrderSummary>
  {% endfor -%}
                </GetOpenOrdersResult>
            </GetOpenOrdersResponse>
        </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
</set-body>
```

I can see two potential problems with your request.

1. You might be missing `SOAPAction` header, example for submitOrder

```
<set-header name="SOAPAction" exists-action="override">
    <value>http://tempuri.org/IFazioService/submitOrder</value>
</set-header>
```

2. Also you may want to set backend url and rewrite path to the resource (if APIM path is different than the SOAP service)

```
<set-backend-service base-url="{{s-iserve-store-inventory-backend-url}}" />
<rewrite-uri template="?" copy-unmatched-params="false" />
```